# Максимальное значение в массиве

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, x86

Есть задание. Необходимо найти значение максимального элемента в массиве. Элементы массива должны иметь тип `WORD` (2 байта). В первом элементе массива должно хранить количество элементов массива −1. То есть оттуда мы должны считать количество чисел, перейти на адрес второй ячейки массива, и начиная с числа по этому адресу уже сравнивать.

Написал следующий код:

```
section .text
   global _start 
    
_start: 
        
   mov  eax, 3    ; mov eax, [x]
   mov  ebx,0      ; EBX будет хранить максимальное значение
   mov  ecx, x    ; ECX будет указывать на текущий элемент для выполнения операции сравнения
   add ecx, 2 
 
top:  cmp ebx, [ecx]
   JNS l1
   mov ebx, [ecx]
   l1: add  ecx, 2      ; перемещаем указатель на следующий элемент
   dec  eax        ; выполняем декремент счётчика
   jnz  top        ; если счётчиком не является 0, то тогда выполняем цикл ещё раз
 
done: 
 
   add   ebx, '0'
   mov  [max], ebx ; готово, сохраняем результат в переменной sum
 
display:
 
   mov  edx, 2      ; длина сообщения
   mov  ecx, max   ; сообщение для написания
   mov  ebx, 1     ; файловый дескриптор (stdout)
   mov  eax, 4     ; номер системного вызова (sys_write)
   int  0x80       ; вызов ядра
    
   mov  eax, 1     ; номер системного вызова (sys_exit)
   int  0x80       ; вызов ядра
 
section .data
global x
x:
   dw  3
   dw  2
   dw  4
   dw  3
 
max: 
   dw  0
```

Компилирую в Linux через консоль, компиляция проходит, но результат выводит неправильный. Кроме того, ему не нравится синтаксис(segmentation fault)

```
mov eax, [x]
```

Если кто разбирается в ассемблере, помогите, пожалуйста. Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка у вас вот здесь:

> ```
> top:  cmp ebx, [ecx] ← ошибка
>    JNS l1
>    mov ebx, [ecx] ← ошибка
> ```

Вы помещаете в `ebx` двойное слово — 4 байта, начиная с адреса `[ecx]`, а нужно поместить всего 2 байта:

```
top:
    cmp WORD bx, [ecx]
    jns l1
    mov WORD bx, [ecx]
```

Ну и везде далее по коду нужно разобраться с размерностью регистров.